# How can we handle long running processes using serverless architecture in azure?

Tags: azure, timeout, serverless, handle, long-running-processes

I'm looking for something similar to ECS task where it will just run the long running task like terraform scripts without any time limit.
Do we have any better approach in serverless architecture where we can just ask to perform a long running task and wait till it gets completed without timeout. Also we can not logically break the functionality or store the current status of the task and call the other function to perform the task.

I have already explored durable function where each function (starter/orchestrator/activity) still has the time limit. In AWS we can ask lambda to trigger ecs task and ecs task can perform the long running process. I'm looking for something similar in azure.

Comment: generally speeking you shoud have a look at this document where you can found azure equivalent services for aws ( this doc helps people with aws background to onboard faster on azure) url : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services. In your case maybe azue container apps with azure function would do the job.

Comment: but any idea how azure function can trigger azure container app ?

Comment: seems this url could be a good starting point : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-azure-function-trigger

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, This document would help if we want to trigger container instances and not container app from azure function